# How to include Android libraries and classes for Sonar?

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I try to use last `SonarQube` plugin for `Gradle` on an Android project.

I follow this:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle

My root.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

My app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 17
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        versionCode 232
        versionName "2.3.2"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "xxxxx"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.java.binaries","build/intermediates/classes"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java"
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/lint-results.xml"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/debug/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I run

```
./gradlew sonarqube  -Dsonar.verbose=true
```

Logs:

```
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:sonarqube
Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.libraries property
sonar.binaries and sonar.libraries are deprecated since version 2.5 of sonar-java-plugin, please use sonar.java.binaries and sonar.java.libraries instead
Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of test files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.test.libraries property

Class 'com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/ChangelogActivity' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
Class 'com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/ChangelogActivity$1' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
Class 'com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/ConfigActivity' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
Class 'com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/ConfigActivity$1' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
```

I obtain this error msg on all my classes.

Comment: try this gradle... dependencies {
    compile 'com.qualinsight.plugins.sonarqube:qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-licensing:1.0.0'
}

Comment: Why add this plugin ? the description of this plugin : QualInsight licensing library for securing commercial plugins. What's the link with my issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately due to complexity of Android Gradle projects (ability to have several flavors in a single project for example) we are not able to automatically collect all information we need to run a SonarQube analysis without any extra config.

Please follow: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-6

Comment: Thanks for info. what's the alternative to analyse Android-Gradle application in sonar ?

Comment: You have to provide all required properties manually, especially sonar.java.libraries and sonar.java.binaries. This can be a bit tedious since sonar.java.libraries should probably list many JARs from Android SDK.